# Explicit specialization of Member after instantiation - Only in Xcode

Tags: c++, xcode

I have a software which I am compiling, that compiles and works fine on Windows 10 with VS2015 and Ubuntu 16.04 with g++ 5.4. But on the latest version of Xcode, it does not.

I have a header class with the following:

```
  template<typename Dtype>
  string device_type_name() const;

  virtual string device_type_name_void() const = 0;
  virtual string device_type_name_bool() const = 0;
```

And I have the implementation as such:

```
template<>
string DeviceProgram::device_type_name<void>() const {
  return device_type_name_void();
}
template<>
string DeviceProgram::device_type_name<bool>() const {
  return device_type_name_bool();
}
```

Unfortunately, only on osx I get the error:

```
device_program.cpp:410: error: explicit specialization of 'device_type_name<bool>' after instantiation
```

I tried to remove the `string device_type_name() const;` etc. instantiation line, but if I do that, then I get the errors:

```
device_program.cpp:409: error: extraneous 'template<>' in declaration of variable 'device_type_name'

device_program.cpp:410: error: redefinition of 'device_type_name'
```

Furthermore, I am unable to do things like:

`this->device_type_name<Dtype>()`

Please help